# How to solve $\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}u=\omega$

Tags: reference-request, potential-theory, several-complex-variables

I'm looking for references on the study of the equation $\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}u=\omega$,especially when $\omega$ is a k\"ahler metric on $\Omega\setminus S$,where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $S$ a submanifold of codimension 2.

In the simplest case,let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ be a small polydisc centered at origin,$\omega$ a k\"ahler form on $\Omega\setminus\{0\}$ satisfying $d\omega=0$.Then $\omega$ can be extended to a unique $d$-closed positive current $\tilde{\omega}$ with $L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ coefficients.Shrinking $\Omega$ if necessary,we get $\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}u=\tilde{\omega}$ for a plurisubharmonic function $u$.

Can we solve $u$ explictly?Or at least do we know any properties that $u$ possesses?For example,I know $u$ is smooth wherever $\omega$ is smooth by standard interior regularity.Moreover,by a lemma due to Griffith,$\int_{\Omega'\setminus \{0\}}(\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}u)^2<+\infty$.Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?  These things (which are called kahler potentials) are very well studied.  In particular, on a kahler manifold, the metric can always be written locally as $i\partial \bar{\partial} u$ for some locally defined potential $u$ (This is a version of the poincare lemma).  You will not always get one which is well defined on the whole manifold:  this is a question of dolbeault cohomology. Also, you seem to be implying that such a $u$ is unique, which is far from the truth since (for example) you could add any harmonic function and still have a solution.

Comment: @StevenGubkin I want to express $u$ explicitly,not just an asurance of existence.I know in some textbook it always says there exists a potential $u$ that...But can we write out what on earth $u$ is?

Comment: This is a hard problem, since $u$ is only defined up to a harmonic function, and these are quite flexible.  You could explicitly solve it locally (say on a polydisc).  Is that what you are after?

Comment: There is a lot of technology for engineering solutions to these kinds of equations having all sorts of prescribed properties.  For example, Hormander's method.

Comment: @StevenGubkin And the k\"ahler metric here is singular along a submanifold $S$ of codim 2.I want to study the behavior of the k\"ahler potential near $S$ if I can't solve this equation.Can you tell me what key words should I google? 'Hormander's method' seems too vague.

Comment: https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/estimations_l2.pdf has a lot of what you (probably) want.

Comment: It would really help if you could refine this question.  What kind of properties are you interested in?  Is there a particular growth condition you want as you approach this submanifold?  Have you solved the case of the bidisc minus a point already?